# Django - Accessing extra ModelForm fields in a different template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a first view (createview) which calls a ModelForm that has an extra field added to it.
The first view leads to a second view (detailview), where i need to access the fields from the previous ModelForm to show them in the template.
For the fields belonging to the model, i used {{ object.fieldname }} in the template and it works.
The problem that remains is how to access the field i added myself.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Django Session. Chexk on the link in doccumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/)

in your form view

```
    if form.is_valid():
                request.session['extra_field'] = form.cleaned_data['extra_field']
...
```

On the next page view get back the saved data on session

```
def your_checkout_view(request):
    extra_field = request.session['extra_field']
...
```

Comment: Thank you! i got inspired by this and adapted it to my class based views : 

def form_valid(self, form):
       self.request.session['extra_field'] = form.cleaned_data['extra_field ']

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['extra_field '] = self.request.session['extra_field ']